# Why has Mozilla created conditional catch clause?

Tags: javascript, exception, mozilla

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch#Conditional_catch_clauses

So this question's just for curiosity... why (and under what conditions) has Mozilla created this not-standard structure? What is the problem this feature is supposed to solve?

And why not create something like that and check prototype under the hood?

```
try {}
catch(TypeError e) {}
catch(RangeError e) {}
catch(e) {}
```

Comment: Rather than relying on off-site content and making people go off-site to help you, summarize the content of the link **in** your question.

Comment: What does *"and under what conditions"* mean?

Comment: [Brendan Eich](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/conditional-catch-clause#content-10): "*The catch (e if cond) syntax is in SpiderMonkey and Rhino, dates from ES3 where it was proposed, prototyped, and shot down in Ecma TC39 TG1, but kept in the implementations.*"

Answer (score 0):

They created it because they felt that it needed to be in the language. They can do so because they control SpiderMonkey (and, technically, JavaScript [the Mozilla-only language implemented by SpiderMonkey] as distinct from ECMAScript [the standardized language we all call "JavaScript"]). They made it an `if` with arbitrary conditions rather than something more like Java because it's more flexible if you can test anything, not just `instanceof` or similar.

There's currently no proposal to add this to <s>JavaScript</s> ECMAScript, nor does there [seem to be much appetite for doing so](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/standardizing-conditional-try-catch) in isolation. (There's *some* interest in generalized [pattern matching](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-pattern-matching), currently a [Stage 0](https://tc39.github.io/process-document/) proposal, which could evolve into something that also got applied to `catch`.)

But using logic *inside* the `catch` block and re-throwing became more attractive since some consensus has been reached to make call stack generation happen at exception *creation* time rather than at `throw` (sadly IE11 gets it wrong, but that will stop being a problem someday).